# $x=yx$. Can this statement be true when we don't know that $y=1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, paradoxes

I am dealing with an equation which is saying that $yx=x$. On the other hand it is telling us that $\frac{x}{x}=1$ which connotes that $x=x$. Is it not absurd to say that $x=x=yx$ when we don't know that $y=1$ here.

Comment: $yx=x \implies yx-x = 0 \implies x(y-1)=0 \implies x= 0 \text{ or } y = 1$

Comment: How do you get $\frac xx=1$ ??

Comment: By diving both sides by $x$.

Comment: This gives $y=\frac xx=1$ but can only be derived if $x\ne0$. And when $x=0$, the equation is obviously fulfilled, whatever $y$.

Comment: There is no absurdity in deriving that $x=x=xy$. The first equality is a tautology and the second is a given.

Comment: What we would get if we divide two equal quantities when they are unequal to zero? certainly, we would get 1 as in the case above when I divided $x$ by $x$, taking that $x$ is not equal to zero, I got $1$.

Comment: I wrote there, "when we don't know that $y=1$".

Comment: The fact that $x=x$ and that $\frac{x}{x}=1$ when $x \neq 0$ are indeed true. I don't see what is the problem for you, though.

Comment: By the problem statement, you do know that either $y=1$ or $x=0$. If you also know that $y\ne1$, then $x=0$.

Comment: I think, I am confused.

Comment: $y>0$ and $x=\pm\infty$ is also satisfy your equation. Correct conditions should be $$yx=x,x\not=\pm\infty \implies yx-x = 0 $$

Comment: Don't consider the question please. It's vague and I am sorry to post it so early without seeing it rigorously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dividing both sides of the equation by $x$ is valid provided $x\neq 0$. Note how doing so left out solution $x=0$. Instead, bring all terms to one side of the equation, factor, and solve.

$$x = yx \iff x - yx = 0 \iff x(1-y) = 0 \implies x=0 \text{ or } y = 1$$

Comment: What if we divide both sides by x? The solution then be, $x=x$ and $y=1$.

Comment: @SufyanSheikh You can't divide by $0$.  Therefore you can't divide by $x$ without first assuming $x \ne 0$.

Comment: By dividing by $x$, you lose the solution $x = 0$. See my comment at the start of my post.

Comment: If I assume that $x\neq{0}$ then what will be the solution? Will it be like $y=0$ and $x=x$?

Comment: If $x\neq 0$ then the solution would be $y = 1$. One of the following must be true, if the equation is true. Either $x = 0$ (then y can be anything), or else if $x\neq 0$, then $y = 1$, where x can be any value whatsoever except $0$.

Answer (score 3):

$x = yx\implies yx - x = 0\implies (y - 1)x = 0\implies x = 0$ or $y = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Write the equation as $x(y-1)=0$. At least one factor must be zero, so that the solution is
$$y=1\lor x=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $x=0$, then $y$ must not necessarily be $1$, since any number multiplied by $0$ is $0$.

Suppose, instead, that $x\neq 0$, than you can divide both sides of the equation to get: $$\frac{x}{x}=y$$ and therefore $y=1$

I guess you're asking whether stating that $xy=x$ (when $x\neq 0)$ is absurd if we don't know, beforehand, that $y=1$. Well, it is if $y$ is already defined in some way and from that you deduce $y\neq 1$. But it is not if you are trying to find the set of solutions of the equation $xy=x$, where $x$ and $y$ are just arbitrary real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about real numbers or integers? There are rings $R$ such that there are elements $a, b \neq 0$ with $ab=0$ (Take $\mathbb{Z}_6$ and $a=2, b=3$). In that case you cannot conclude $y=1$ from $xy=x$ for a single value of $x$.

In the example $y*3 = (y+2)*3$ for any $y$